# The distance of an object undergoing constant acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, distance

Is the distance an object moving increases with time if it is accelerated with a constant rate?

I mean, doesn't it depend on the direction the object is traveling? if I throw an object upward, wouldn't the distance it travels per second decrease due to the deceleration of gravity?

This was the question, it was from my final PHYS101 exam:

> **If an object is undergoing constant acceleration, the distance it travels per second is:**
>
> A. Increasing with time
> B. Decreasing with time
> C. Constant with time
> D. Depends on the direction it travels

Comment: @John Having answer D as a possibility implies we should not assume an initial zero velocity.

Comment: I edited the post to write the exact question (I forget adding something). I don't know if it would make a difference.

Comment: I would choose D, but as a physicist I would say is badly worded. It would be better if it said "Depends on the direction it travels relative to the acceleration"

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely ambiguity with your exam. Acceleration can refer to deceleration, but sometimes people consider these two to be separate.

After re-reading the exact question asked, whether or not it is accelerating or decelerating is irrelevant. Even if it is decelerating, the object will still be moving forward and hence the distance should be increase.

The ambiguity here is, distance with respect to what?

Comment: That's why I chose D

Comment: @GhassanSaeed What's the problem?

Comment: I believe the right answer is A, as most of my friends said, but Im not convinced.

Comment: @GhassanSaeed Without thinking of edge cases, I'm not surprised people would say it's A. I'd recommend asking for a regrade request from the professor.

Comment: I edited the post to write the exact question (I forget adding something). I don't know if it would make a difference.

Comment: @JobHunter69, it is very easy to write an ambiguous exam question, and there are many examples.  As an example, when I was teaching high school physics, I wrote several exam questions that I thought were clearly worded, only to have a few students ask some interesting questions regarding my hidden assumptions that led to the need for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't give us enough data for an answer but I will point out 3 cases:

1) For an object without any velocity, the correct answer is (a). The direction of acceleration is not important since it is moving away from a point, so the total space covered by the object would be the same.

2) For an object with constant velocity, if the direction of the velocity is the same with the direction of the acceleration, then the correct answer is (a), since the object will gain velocity.

3) For an object with constant velocity, if the direction of the velocity is opposite to the direction of the acceleration, then the correct answer is (b), since the object will lose velocity.

Answer (score 0):

D depends on the direction it travels,
an example of this is the uniform circular motion, it has a constant acceleration although the velocity itself is not changing... the acceleration (squared) is the sum of both tangential and normal acceleration (each squared),
the tangential acceleration is null since the speed is constant, meaning that the covered distance with time is constant.
yet the normal acceleration has a value since the direction of velocity is changing.
so it just depends on the direction of velocity